# Why does my audio function keep looping instead of running all the way through?

Tags: c, function, audio

My code is working apart from my "play" function. I'm trying to make the program read the .txt files created by the "record" function and play the notes back.

Unfortunately, when the user presses <kbd>P</kbd> to play back the notes they have recorded, it just keeps popping up with the same menu, instead of advancing to the next step of the program.

```
#include "aservelibs/aservelib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

float mtof(int note, float frequency);
FILE play(void);
FILE record(void);
FILE record2(void);

int main()
{
   FILE *textFilePointer;
   FILE *textFilePointer2;
   int counter = 0;
   char user;

   do
   {
      printf("Press A to Record 1st Melody (A), B to Record 2nd Melody (B)\nP to Play Melodies (P):");
      scanf(" %c", &user);

      if (user == 'a' || user == 'A')
      {
         textFilePointer = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes1.txt", "w");
         *textFilePointer = record();
         counter = 0;
      }

      else if (user == 'b' || user == 'B')
      {
         textFilePointer2 = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes2.txt", "w");
         *textFilePointer2 = record2();
         counter = 0;
      }

      else if (user == 'p' || user == 'P')
      {
         textFilePointer = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes1.txt", "r");
         textFilePointer2 = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes2.txt", "r");
         counter = 0;
      }
   }
   while(counter < 16);
}

float mtof(int note, float frequency)
{
   frequency = 440.0 * pow(2, (note-69) / 12.0);
   printf("%d\n", note);
   return frequency;
}

FILE play(void)
{
   FILE*file;
   file = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes1.txt", "r");
   file = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes1.txt", "r");

   do {

      int note = aserveGetNote();
      int velocity = aserveGetVelocity();
      fscanf(file, "%d, %d\n", &note, &velocity);
      int frequency = mtof(note, frequency);
      aserveOscillator(0, frequency, 1.0, 0);
      aserveSleep(500);
   } while (feof(file) == 0);

   fclose(file);
   return *file;
}

FILE record(void)
{
   int counter;
   FILE*file;
   file = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes1.txt", "w");

   do
   {

      int note = aserveGetNote();
      int velocity = aserveGetVelocity();
      if (velocity > 0)
      {
         fprintf(file, "%d, %d\n", note, velocity);
         counter++;
      }


   } while (counter < 16);
   fclose(file);
   return *file;
}

FILE record2(void)
{
   int counter;
   FILE*file;
   file = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes2.txt", "w");

   do
   {

      int note = aserveGetNote();
      int velocity = aserveGetVelocity();
      if (velocity > 0)
      {
         fprintf(file, "%d, %d\n", note, velocity);
         counter++;
      }


   } while (counter < 16);
   fclose(file);
   return *file;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   fclose(file);
   return *file;
```

If you close it, you can no longer use it. Don't close `file` if you expect to still use it later (which you do).

Answer (score 2):

**Issues that I see with your program**

1. When the user enters `A` or `a`, you execute:

   ```
    textFilePointer = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes1.txt", "w");
    *textFilePointer = record();
    counter = 0;
   ```

   The code for recording to `"/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes1.txt"` is already hard coded in `record()`. There is no need to use `fopen()` on the same file here.

   `record()` doesn't need to return a `FILE`. As an aside, use of `FILE` as return type seems strange. I don't think the standard even supports use of `FILE`. Use of `FILE*` as an argument and a return value are what I have seen.

   Same thing applies to `record2()`.
2. When the user enters `p` or `P`, you execute:

   ```
    textFilePointer = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes1.txt", "r");
    textFilePointer2 = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes2.txt", "r");
    counter = 0;
   ```

   There is no call to `play()` here. Perhaps that got lost while you were transcribing your code to post here. Even if add a line

   ```
    play();
   ```

   there, there is no need to use `fopen()` here. `play()` already opens the file(s) for playing. Also, you are opening the file multiple times and not using them or closing them.
3. You are setting `counter` to `0` in all the three `if` blocks in `main`. When will value of `counter` be `16` to meet the exit criterion of the `do-while` loop? Is this an oversight?
4. In the implementation of `play()`, you have:

   ```
   file = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes1.txt", "r");
   file = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes1.txt", "r");
   ```

   That does not look right. You are calling `fopen` on the same file twice. You are leaving a unused and open `FILE*` when the function returns.

   The second file never gets played.

   I am going to suggest creation of a helper function, `playFile()`, which does the needful to play the contents of a given file. Then, call `playFile()` twice from `play()`. Here's the pseudo code:

   ```
   void playFile(char const* file)
   {
      FILE* file = fopen(file, "r);

      if ( file == NULL )
      {
         // deal with error.
      }
      else
      {
         // Your code to play the contents.

         // Close the file
         fclose(file);
      }
   }

   void play()
   {
      playFile("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes1.txt");
      playFile("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes2.txt");
   }
   ```

**Follow [the DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)**

I am going to suggest creating a function `recordToFile()` that has the common code of `record()` and `record2()`, then calling it from `record()` and `record2()` with the right argument.

```
void recordToFile(char const* file)
{
   int counter;
   FILE* file = fopen(file, "w");
   if ( file == NULL )
   {
      // Deal with error
   }
   else
   {
      // Your code to record to the file.

      // Close the file
      fclose(file);
   }
}

void record(void)
{
   recordToFile("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes1.txt");
}

void record2(void)
{
   recordToFile("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes2.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never call the play function as in:

```
else if (user == 'p' || user == 'P')
{
   ...
   play ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that after your second call to fopen:

```
   file = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes1.txt", "r");
   file = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes1.txt", "r");
```

The FILE * `file` will be invalid.  At the very least, they are redundant.
You should delete one of these lines.

Also, check that `file` is valid before using:

```
file = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes1.txt", "r");
if(file) //if fopen fails, file == NULL
{
    do {
    ...
```